# what ADO.Net version is currenlty used in ASP.net MVC 2?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

Current ASP.Net MVC 2 uses Linq to SQL or Linq to entites? i am using VS 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 2 can also be used with normal ADO.NET. What you use for your data access has nothing to do with what technology you use on the UI side of your architecture.

What probably confuses you a bit at this moment is that you see mostly examples written with Linq to Sql or Entity Framework. However these could also be written with other technologies like Subsonic or NHibernate.

Read this article: [Extending NerdDinner: Exploring Different Database Options](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions.aspx). It shows the following technologies:

- ADO.NET Connected (DataReaders)
- ADO.NET Disconnected (DataSets)
- LINQ to SQL
- LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework)

Comment: thanks XIII, i just started look in to that MVC and Entity framework.. thanks for the link.. :)